# Invoke cfc from cfc called by web service

Tags: coldfusion

I am wanting to invoke a cfc from a cfc that is consumed as a web service. The web service just returns a status notification back to the caller but I need to fire off another cfc to start some processes that opens a ftp gets a file and downloads it to our server. Currently I am getting this error.
Action  GetFile
Cause   550 Failed to open file.
Detail  Error: 550 Failed to open file. .
Message An error occurred during the FTP GetFile operation.  open file. .

When I invoke the process cfc directly from a url or invoke from another page it works fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Web Service code:

```
    <cfargument name="FileName" required="yes" type="string">
    <cfargument name="BatchNumber" required="yes" type="numeric">
    <cfargument name="LOGIN_USERID" required="yes" type="string">
    <cfargument name="LOGIN_PASSWORD" required="yes" type="string">


    <cfset comparison = Compare(LOGIN_PASSWORD, "xxxxxxx")>

    <cfif (LOGIN_USERID EQ "myid") AND (comparison EQ 0)>

        <cfset xmlDoc = XmlNew()>
        <cfset xmlDoc.XMLRoot = XMLElemNew(xmlDoc,"batchfiles")>
        <cfset xmlDoc.batchfiles.XmlChildren[1] = XmlElemNew(xmlDoc,"batch")>
        <cfset arrayappend(xmlDoc.batchfiles.XmlChildren[1].xmlChildren, XmlElemNew(xmlDoc,"batchnumber"))>
        <cfset xmlDoc.batchfiles.XmlChildren[1].batchnumber.XMLText="#batchnumber#">
        <cfset arrayappend(xmlDoc.batchfiles.XmlChildren[1].xmlChildren, XmlElemNew(xmlDoc,"filename"))>
        <cfset xmlDoc.batchfiles.XmlChildren[1].filename.XMLText="#filename#">
        <cfset arrayappend(xmlDoc.batchfiles.XmlChildren[1].xmlChildren, XmlElemNew(xmlDoc,"status"))>
        <cfset xmlDoc.batchfiles.XmlChildren[1].status.XMLText="Notification Received OK">



        <cfinvoke component="ImportRCMOrders" method="GetRCMOrderFiles">
            <cfinvokeargument name="FileName" value="#filename#">
            <cfinvokeargument name="BatchNumber" value="#batchnumber#">
        </cfinvoke>


        <cfreturn xmlDoc>   


    <cfelse>

        <cfoutput>Unauthorized Access. Please check username / password and ty again.</cfoutput>
        <cfabort>

    </cfif>
```

Entire Error:
Action  GetFile
Cause   550 Failed to open file.
Detail  Error: 550 Failed to open file. .
Message An error occurred during the FTP GetFile operation.
StackTrace  coldfusion.tagext.net.FtpHandler$FtpOperationException: An error occurred during the FTP GetFile operation. at coldfusion.tagext.net.FtpHandler.checkError(FtpHandler.java:189) at coldfusion.tagext.net.FtpHandler.getFile(FtpHandler.java:682) at coldfusion.tagext.net.FtpTag.doStartTag(FtpTag.java:763) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2991) at cfImportRCMOrders2ecfc184096832$funcGETRCMORDERFILES.runFunction(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\imarkwebservice\rcm\dynamic\ImportRCMOrders.cfc:56) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:487) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:420) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:383) at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:334) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:533) at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:648) at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:457) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2424) at coldfusion.tagext.lang.InvokeTag.doEndTag(InvokeTag.java:399) at cfcfc_init2ecfm454010022.runPage(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\imarkwebservice\rcm\dynamic\cfc_init.cfm:14) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:246) at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:736) at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:572) at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65) at coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:45) at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:487) at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:42) at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40) at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:142) at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94) at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:78) at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28) at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38) at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:58) at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38) at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22) at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62) at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219) at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42) at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:422) at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:199) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

GetRCMOrderFiles:

```
    <!--- Open FTP connection --->
    <cfftp connection ="FTPRequest"
        action ="OPEN"
        username ="xxxxxx"
        password ="xxxx"
        server ="ftp.server.com"
        stopOnError ="Yes" 
        timeout="36000">


    <!--- List directories --->
    <cfftp connection = "FTPRequest"
        action = "LISTDIR"
        stopOnError = "Yes"
        name = "ftpQuery"            
        directory = "#arguments.ftpOrdersDir#"> 


    <!--- Download ftp files --->
    <cfif ftpQuery.recordcount GT 0>
        <cfif ftpQuery.Name EQ  arguments.filename>
            <cfset extension = LCase(listLast(arguments.filename,".")) >
            <cfif extension EQ 'csv'>

                <cftry>
                    <!--- Download ftp files --->
                    <cfftp connection = "FTPRequest"
                        action = "GetFile"
                        name = "dlFiles" 
                        remotefile="#ftpOrdersDir##arguments.filename#" 
                        localfile="#ExpandPath('/mydir/dynamic/orders/'& arguments.filename)#" 
                        failifexists="no" 
                        stoponerror="yes"> 

                    <!--- Rename files in ftp processed dir --->
                    <cfftp connection = "FTPRequest"
                        action = "RENAME"
                        existing="#arguments.ftpOrdersDir##arguments.filename#"
                        new="#arguments.ftpOrdersDir##arguments.filename#.#DateFormat(Now(), 'mmddyyyy')##Hour(Now())##Minute(Now())##Second(Now())#"
                        stopOnError = "Yes">

                <cfcatch type="any">
                    <cfmail type="html" 
                        to="email@myemailacct.com" 
                        from="FTPProcess@myemailacct.com" 
                        subject="FTP Error"> 
                        <p> An error occurred on #DateFormat( Now(), "mmm d, yyyy" )# at #TimeFormat( Now(), "hh:mm TT" )# </p> 
                        Error Message: #cfcatch.message#<br> 
                        Error Detail: #cfcatch.detail#<br> 
                        Error Location: #GetBaseTemplatePath()#<br>
                        <cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
                        </cfmail>
                    <cfabort>
                </cfcatch>
                </cftry>
            </cfif>
```

This is from the first function that is called as the web service.
  struct: 
  BATCHNUMBER   35506
  FILENAME  batchfile_35506.csv
  LOGIN_PASSWORD    password
  LOGIN_USERID  userid

struct
  BATCHNUMBER   35506
  FILENAME  batchfile_35506.csv
 FTPORDERSDIR   /Dir/35506/

Comment: Post the entire error message and some code from the `getRCMOrders()` method.

Comment: What access type you have set for the function? You may set the `access` scope of the function to `remote` and check if it solves your issue.

Comment: Both functions are set as Remote access type.

Answer (score 1):

A 550 from the FTP client means that the file or directory does not exist. Check that your path is correct and that the file does exist at that path and that the user you are logging in as (on the FTP call) has permissions to this file.

I am assuming that the GetRCMOrderFiles() function is trying to retrieve a file from FTP?

You should be catching these as exceptions as well and possibly checking that the file exists before doing a get.

Comment: The file does exist and the path is correct. As I stated above when I run GetRCMOrderFiles() from a page by itself it works fine. It only errors out when it is called from within the web service cfc.

Comment: Can you dump the arguments on the call from both calls, one from the web service and one from a page by itself? - <cfdump var="#arguments#" />

Comment: I posted the arguments dump above. After running this I received the error message as stated above. I think there is an issue with invoking a function from a web service but I can't find anything on the web about it.

Comment: Ok guys, I have found the answer. I failed to read this statement in the docs. "Note  Names of objects (files and directories) are case-sensitive; thus, using ListDir on "test.log " will not find a file named "test.LOG." The file name was BatchFile_35506.csv but the arguments was batchfile_35506.csv. I appreciate everyones help. Nothing like feeling like an idiot.